# Lost Strings upper and lowercase

Tags: python

I need to figure out if an entire string is completely lowercase or uppercase.

The output should be like this for all uppercase:

```
All Uppercase: Yes
```

And like this for all lowercase

```
All Uppercase: No
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
if all str.upper() for str in user_string 
print ("All uppercase: Yes")
else
print ("All uppercase: No")
```

But it doesn't print the correct strings.

Comment: `if string == string.lower() or string == string.upper(): ...`

Comment: **What you do?** Try something yourself, for starters.

Comment: Sorry, Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Have you tried something already and run into a problem? If so, please post the code you have so far and what exactly you're having problems with

Comment: @alfasin Please do not post answers in comments.

Comment: if all str.upper() print ("All uppercase: Yes")

Comment: JSH, please edit your post to include this

Otherwise, this is fine except that str is a variable already taken, try something else.

Comment: that its what i tired

Comment: @DimitrisJim I did!!! LOOK

Comment: @FullCombatBeard Thanks Alot I appreciate it

Comment: @alfasin Thanks and yeah i edited it to show what i did

Comment: @Darendal I know that. Look now i put my work in the post.

Comment: JSH, you are missing a colon after your conditionals. so after an if or else statement, add a : to the end

Comment: @JSH, if you have received a good answer, please mark it as so

Answer (score 3):

use`islower()` or `isupper()`

So, assuming you're reading from input:

```
x = input()
print(x.isupper()) #true if all uppercase
print(x.islower()) #true if all lowercase
```

Answer (score 1):

Use isupper() and islower() functions to check.

```
text = input("Enter the text in upper or lower case only:")
print(text.isupper()) #true if all uppercase
print(text.islower()) #true if all lowercase
```